# How to assign value to procedure's struct parameter?

Tags: c, struct

I'm making a program to input some data to array of struct. When I tried to assign temporary struct `temp` to procedure's struct parameter `*daf`, the program's always force closed. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int num;
  char name[50];
  float value;
} Mhs;

typedef Mhs ListMhs[50];
void inputData(int nEf, ListMhs *daf);

int main() {
  ListMhs listmhs;
  inputData(5, &listmhs);
  return 0;
}

void inputData(int nEf, ListMhs *daf) {
  int i;
  ListMhs temp;
  for (i=0; i<nEf; i++) {
    printf("Num: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp[i].num);

    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &temp[i].name);

    printf("Value: ");
    scanf("%f", &temp[i].value);
  }

  //assign value
  for (i=0; i<nEf; i++) {
    *daf[i] = temp[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: No error, the program just force closed / stopped working. When I tried to compile, the program stopped working in third loop or when i=2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in the line `*daf[i] = temp[i];`

`[]` has higher precedence than `*`

So it should be  `(*daf)[i] = temp[i];`

The original line `*daf[i] = temp[i];` is actually `*(daf[i]) = temp[i];`and was trying to treat `daf` as an array of `ListMhs` and taking the `i`th element of it and then dereferencing it. Obviously as you were only passing in a pointer to one ListMhs, as soon as i was greater than 0 you would have problems. The program probably tried to write to protected memory after the second or third iteration, which is why it hard crashed. If you had a debugger of some sort attached you would have probably got a more helpful error.

Here is the list of C++ operator precedence: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence